# Popen not writing stdout to file

Tags: python

I am running another python background process within a python script and am trying to pipe its stdout to a file. I am running:

```
with open("log.log", "wb") as out:
    p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "main.py"], stdout=out, bufsize=1)
```

However, the file is always empty while I can see in shell the output of the popen process just fine. Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to save main.py output in the log.log file?

Comment: Yes indeed @omides248

Comment: This is standard buffering. `wait` for the process and it will close the file, which flushes output through to the disk. But probably don't use `Popen` at all if you can avoid it; as suggested in the `subprocess` documentation, prefer `run` when you can. Then you don't need to `wait` explicitly because `run` takes care of managing the `Popen` object properly and shutting it down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **buffering=1** for write realtime to file.
[python write to file in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54134177/python-write-to-file-in-real-time)

and use w+ for append

test.py:

```
import subprocess

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    with open("log.log", "w+", buffering=1) as f:
        p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "main.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        for line in p.stdout:
            f.write(line.decode("utf-8"))
```

main.py:

```
import random
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        print(f"Hello {random.randint(1, 100)}")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `shell=True` is an error when the first argument is a list. Weirdly, it works on Windows; but it's still a bug and a very common error.

Comment: And having Python read and then write the output is just inefficient; the OP's original code was better.

Comment: Assuming UTF-8 encoding hampers portability; there is no particular reason here to not simply read and write `bytes`, which will be more efficient, too. (But the proper fix is to do neither; see the previous comment.)